# Few questions about Mergesort and Recirsion algorithms

Tags: algorithm-analysis, sorting, recursion

1. Can we use recursive algorithm to find the greatest element of a finite list when numbers are unsorted.
2. How to use recursive algorithm to find the least element of a finite list of unsorted numbers where repetitions of number is allowed.
3. How can Mergesort calls itself n^2 times on a list with n numbers.
4. Is it true if the input list has only 3 numbers, then Mergesort does not need the merging step.
5. Can we find number of elements in a finite list with a
   recursive algorithm.

Little explanations will be helpful to understand, thank you.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: its not a homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be hard to understand numbers 3 and 4 until you're solid on the others. I'd suggest looking closely at the definition of recursion. A solid understanding of recursion is crucial to a lot of computer science.

But for answers, if it helps at all:

> Can we use recursive algorithm to find the greatest element of a finite list when numbers are unsorted.

```
def greatest(list):
    first = list[0]
    remaining = list[1:]
    if remaining exists:
        return max(first, greatest(remaining))
    else:
        return first
```

> How to use recursive algorithm to find the least element of a finite list of unsorted numbers where repetitions of number is allowed.

Exactly the same as above, but use `min` instead of `max`.

> How can Mergesort calls itself n^2 times on a list with n numbers.

It doesn't. Mergesort runs in $O(n \log n)$. Are you thinking of Quicksort?

> Is it true if the input list has only 3 numbers, then Mergesort does not need the merging step.

Depends on your implementation. The simple cases of algorithms, when $n$ is so far, tend not to be interesting—but have a lot of potential for bugs. So if I were writing Mergesort, I'd start with something like "if you have less than five numbers, do it by brute force (which is $O(1)$ since we have an upper bound on $n$)".

> Can we find number of elements in a finite list with a recursive algorithm.

```
def count_elements(list):
    if list does not exist: return 0
    return 1 + count_elements(list[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you, so for 4th point, it's not true unless you use brute force?

Comment: @JKLM It depends on your implementation. If I were implementing it, I'd use brute force for that particular case. Others might do it differently.

Comment: so theroticallly it does not need that merging step?

Comment: @JKLM Again, it depends on your implementation. Some implementations would use a merging step there, while others wouldn't.